# How do you turn off auto save on AWS Console Lambda Code Source IDE?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Trying just write code, and autosave keeps firing.

(just trying to add an import statement but autosave absolutely destroys productivity)
[image]

Have Project Settings:

- Customize JavaScript Warnings With .eslintrc - on
- Format on Code Save - on
- Use Built-In JSBeautify as Code Formatter - on

[image]